# Any design pattern for the nested if statements?

Tags: c#

Any design pattern to avoid the following nested if statements? I couldn't come up with any of the design patterns for this situation.

```
    private Message GetMessageFrom(string[] args)
    {
        string id = null, body = null, label = null, path = null;

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            id = args[0];
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                body = args[1];
                if (args.Length > 2)
                {
                    label = args[2];
                    if (args.Length > 3)
                        path = args[3];
                }
            }
        }

        return new Message(id, body, label, path);
    }
```

Comment: Just don't nest them?

Comment: @VladFeinstein if `args` has only one element, that would assign `args[0]` to `path`, when that first argument corresponds to `id`, according to the code in the question.

Comment: Deeply nested if statements should be avoided whenever possible, they get more confusing and less readable the deeper they go. In your example, there's no reason for these ifs to be nested at all, you should just un-nest them and have them one after the other.

Comment: I believe there is a "typo" in code as in each step you should've checked  `>=` and not just `>`

Comment: @Yan `>=` would break it as it is. `if (args.Length >= 0)` would be true even if `args` is empty, and then the code would try to get the first element (that may not exist)

Comment: @st-pat, yep I missed that one, my bad.

Comment: @JeffHartman: Well I don't have to, but if the args has only one item then what is the point even checking for other items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns the default value(`null` in case of reference types like `string`) if the array doesn't contain this index:

```
string id    = args.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
string body  = args.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
string label = args.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
string path  = args.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
return new Message(id, body, label, path);
```

or you could use a `for-loop` and a `switch`:

```
string id = null, body = null, label = null, path = null;
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0: id = args[i]; break;
        case 1: body = args[i]; break;
        case 2: label = args[i]; break;
        case 3: path = args[i]; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `ElementAtOrDefault` looks good but isn't that the case that if the args is null then it's gonna `throw NullArgumentException`? In that case its not good as I want my method to gracefully handle and just give `null`.  

For the second idea-- shouldn't we avoid loops whenever we can?

Comment: @c-sharp: well, if `args` itself is `null` you should handle that separately. Normally i would throw an `ArgumentNullException` in that case. But of course you could also use: `if(args==null)  return new Message(null, null, null, null); else{  ....   }`

Comment: I think calling the generic extension method would be less efficient than my code. As the generic one will check for each item's existence even if the args has only one item.
But your solution would look more clean though.

Comment: @c-sharp - Be careful of premature optimisation. Use brevity over performance until you know that performance is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tim's answer, with no loop, this might be an option :

```
string id = null, body = null, label = null, path = null; 

switch (args.Length) {
     case 4: path  = args[3]; goto case 3;
     case 3: label = args[2]; goto case 2;
     case 2: body  = args[1]; goto case 1;
     case 1: id    = args[0];
}
```

I find it kinda ugly though :)